# Is the formual for winding distribution factor and winding pitch factor for n-phase (intergal-slot winding) machine as 3-phase machine?

Tags: winding

[[image: In Image, alpha is the slot angle and eta'v' is harmonic-ordinal, q= soltsper pole per phase]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlXN2.png) In Image, alpha is the slot angle and eta'v' is harmonic-ordinal, q= solts per pole per phase
[2]All book provide formula for 3-phase winding, and so far no material for n-phase winding.
  Kindly provide me the formula or suggest me literature

Comment: Why not state the formulae you have found and some references. The formula may well be common sense. Seeing what you have will help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this excerpt from John H. Kuhlman "Design of Electrical Apparatus" will help:

[image]